# Auto backup Azure Tables used by a WebApp in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, backup-strategies

My Azure WebApp stores data in Azure Storage Tables and Blob storage. 
There is a backup functionnality, but as I understood it just does not support azure tables/blobs... however I would like to automatically backup my tables to protect against accidental data corruption by users or by a software issue...

I would like to backup `MyProdTables` in `MyBackupBlob` container. Is there away to do it actually?

I read something about [AZCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy), but it seems working with virtual machine's hard drives, but we have the WebApplication as a Service, so I am not sure that it will work in our case...

*Edit*: There is a partial (negative) MS feedback on the question, as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35835994/961631), but it focused rather on migration and entire account snapshots. I am rather focused on the table storage, and maybe even the possibility of backuping individual tables... is strange that is nothing possible in this field, cause *MS Azure Storage Explorer* can easily backup the tables as **CSV** files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in backup feature for blobs and tables, as you've surmised. However: blobs do offer snapshots (a point-in-time snapshot may be taken at any time).

There are also Shared Access Signatures (and Policies) to limit exposure to your storage. And you can even protect the storage account itself from deletion.

As for `AzCopy`: that has nothing to do with VM disks. That's specifically for moving content in and out of blobs and tables.

Comment: is there away to backup the (individual) Azure Tables to CSV files, like Azure Storage Explorer  permits to do, and backup them in a blob container?

Comment: I would surmise that the Azure Storage Explorer folks are using the Data Movement Library, which is the guts of AzCopy as a library. You can see an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library  Having said that, I don't know if it supports tables. If they are exporting tables, they used their own code, or they're calling AzCopy under the covers.