# Azure job for tabular storage data backup

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm new for Azure, Do we have any default job to perform database backup from Azure Tabular storage?.

Comment: It could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835993/how-do-i-backup-azure-tables-and-blobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we have any default job to perform database backup from Azure Tabular storage?.

No, we do not have default job to do it.

Huge demand to backup data directly from the azure Blob/table storage accounts. In order to meet compliance- today users have to move the data to VM and then back it up. This will simplify the current process to take the backup, meet the compliance and BCDR requirements and also save on Cost.

You can give your voice to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/258995-azure-backup/suggestions/33806350-backup-tables-and-blobs) to promote the further to achieve. Or you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835993/how-do-i-backup-azure-tables-and-blobs) to manually backup your table storage.