# How to backup Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to backup azure blob storage?

If we have to maintain a copy in another storage account or subscription, cost will be doubled, right?

Is there a way to perform backup at a reduced cost instead of doubled cost ?

Any other built-in functionality available in azure like back up zipped/compressed blob for backup functions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to backup Azure Blob Storage contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561844/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-azure-blob-storage-contents)

Comment: Take a look at - [Azure Blob Operational Backup for blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76072535/1176573).

Answer (score -1):

Configure your blob storage as cool blob and copy to another cool blob or another storage provider like Google Nearline or S3 IA.