# Azure Blob Operational Backup

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-backup-vault

I have enabled operation backup for containers on a storage account. For this reason I created a new backup vault and a backup policy.

It looks like it's enabled under storage > Data Protection tab but when I go to vault I don't see any backup jobs or policies.

Should I see something here or is this OK?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like it's enabled under storage > Data Protection tab but when I go to vault I don't see any backup jobs or policies.

I have configured a backup policy from storage account to initiate the backups automatically, but the backups are not being initiated in backup vault.

[image]

To resolve the issue, create a backup policy and add the storage account to the backup instance in backup vault. If you created the backup policy from the storage account, it may not have configured the backup frequency to initiate the backup.

Creating a backup policy from storage account.

[image]

Creating a backup policy in a backup vault.

[image]

Backups are initiated successfully.

[image]