# Azure backup database (sql dump file)

Tags: sql, database, azure

I am using azure server for sql database.

I want to enabled backup database daily.
And also need to dump sql file for current database and other images uploaded to server.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

You can install backup software to your azure server and backup your SQL server to azure cloud storage. There are plenty such software (Duplicati, CloudBerry, Acronis etc).
 
Some of them have special features to backup SQL server in a proper way, also there are free versions among them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a different ways. You can use the third party applications and schedule backup jobs. Or you can use the native tools and configure everything by your-self. Hope [this](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-create-a-sql-server-scheduled-backup/) will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going down the Azure services route, for the images you had ought to look at [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs)
And to back it up...[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561844/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-azure-blob-storage-contents)

Answer (score 0):

I know that Cloudberry works with Azure. You can try this software for doing backups daily both full image or icnremental backup.The price is afforable. The tool's simple. I see the person above has already mentioned Cloudberry. Seems to be a good thing.