# Azure blob container backup and recovery

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am thinking of using *Azure Blob Storage* for document management system which I am developing. All Blobs ( images,videos, word/excel/pdf etc) will be stored in Azure Blob storage. As I understand, I need to create container and these files can be stored within the container.

I would like to know how to safeguard against accidental/malicious deletion of the container. If a container is deleted, all the files it contains will be lost. I am trying to figure out how to put backup and recovery mechanism in place for my storage account so that it is always guaranteed that if something happens to a container, I can recover files inside it.

Is there any way provided by Microsoft Azure for such backup and recovery or Do I need explicitly write a code in such a way that files are stored in two separate Blob storage account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Backups**
There are several backup solutions offered for blob storage in case if containers get deleted.more product info can be found here:`https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/`

**Redundancy**

If you are concerned about availability, "The data in your Microsoft Azure storage account is always replicated to ensure durability and high availability. Replication copies your data, either within the same data center, or to a second data center, depending on which replication option you choose." , there are several replication options:

Locally redundant storage (LRS)

Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)

Geo-redundant storage (GRS)

Read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)

More details can be found here:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy
```

**Managing Access**

Finally, managing access to your storage account would be the best way to secure and ensure you'll avoid any loss on your data. You can provide read access only if you don't want anyone to delete files,folders etc.. through the use of **SAS**: Shared Access Signatures, allows you to create policies and provide access based on Read, Write, List, Delete, etc.. A quick GIF demo can be seen here: `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/manage-stored-access-policies-for-storage-accounts-from-within-the-azure-portal/`

Comment: Redundancy should not be mixed with backups: If you delete a blob, it is instantly replica-deleted (well, queued up at least, and once the primary is deleted, you lose access to the replicas queued for deletion). And SAS is not going to help prevent deletion if someone has the access key, as I pointed out. That's only for sharing otherwise-private blobs. And finally: Azure's Backup service is not for backing up blobs.

Comment: Yep totally agree David, i mentioned the 3 areas to cover all corners, backups are still the best way to make sure nothing gets ever deleted permanently :)

Comment: If Backup service worked with blobs, that would be fantastic (hmm - I should post to UserVoice). As far as I am aware, it still doesn't offer a blob-backup mode.

Comment: this thread discusses blob backup options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561844/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-azure-blob-storage-contents

Comment: Right - I'm aware of that. That's merely showing the use of a 3rd party tool, along with a tweak to the API to allow for async blob copy (vs sychronous blob copy, which used to be a major limitation of storage copy).

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with access to your storage account's key (primary or secondary; there are two keys for a storage account) can manipulate the storage account in any way they see fit. The only way to ensure nothing happens? Don't give anyone access to the key(s). If you place the storage account within a resource group that only you have permissions on, you'll at least prevent others with access to the subscription from discovering the storage account and accessing it.

Within the subscription itself, you can place a lock on the actual resource (the storage account), so that nobody with access to the subscription accidentally deletes the entire storage account.

Note: with storage account keys, you do have the ability to regenerate the keys at any time. So if you ever suspected a key was compromised, you can perform a re-gen action.

Comment: One additional step to prevent accidental deletion of container, is to acquire lease on the container for infinite period of time. This prevents "deletion" of container when in "leased" state. Of course, Breaking a lease is possible with just a click of button, still its good idea to put container in leased state. (Add/update/delete of the blob works as usual when container is in "leased" state)

Comment: Azure has also introduced the feature where it is possible to make the container and its contents immutable for specific number of days. This can be handy to implement certain regulations and make sure that data is not modified or deleted accidentally. Settings this policy, also makes the container delete-proof. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage

Answer (score 0):

We are using blob to store documents and for documents management. 
To prevent deletion of the blob, you can now enable soft deletion as described in here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/soft-delete-for-azure-storage-blobs-ga/

You can also create your own automation around powershell,azcopy to do incremental and full backups.
The last element would be to use RA-GRS blobs where you can read from a secondary blob in read mode in another region in case the data center goes down.

**Designing Highly Available Applications using RA-GRS**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-designing-ha-apps-with-ragrs?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fqueues%2ftoc.json

Comment: Thanks Anass. since I posted this question, there have been many improvements. We can also set access policy for container and make it immutable blob storage. Once the policy is set, blobs cannot be deleted accidently or even forcefully. We must de-activate the policy in order to make deletion work again

Answer (score -1):

Use Microsoft's Azure Storage Explorer.  It will allow you to download the full contents of blob containers including folders and subfolders with blobs.  Conversely, you can upload to containers in the same way.  Simple and free!

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, in many escenaries is necessary an automatically process.

Comment: How do you restore a container in az storage explorer?